# Can we use custom equals method for Collection Algorithm

Tags: java

I have a custom class as Student which has two different equals methods (equals, equals1) and have two collections of Student object as list1 and list2. When I do use list1.retainAll(list2), it needs to be used equals1 mechanism instead of eqauls method.

Is this possible or Do we have any API to mention the equals method name when we do have multiple equals mechanism in our customer class.

Example:

```
class Student {

    public String name;

    public Student(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return super.equals(obj);
    }

    public boolean equals1(Object obj) {
        if(obj == null) return false;
        if(!(obj instanceof Student)) return false;
        Student student = (Student) obj;
        if(this.name.equals(student.name)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Student> list1 = new ArrayList<Student>();
        list1.add(new Student("AAA"));
        list1.add(new Student("BCD"));

        List<Student> list2 = new ArrayList<Student>();
        list2.add(new Student("AAA"));
        list2.add(new Student("CDE"));

        // Intersection of list1 and list2
        list1.retainAll(list2);

        for (Student student : list1) {
            System.out.println(student.name);
        }
    }
}
```

The expected result is [AAA] in case if equals1 method is used but in this case, the default equals method is getting executed so that the result is empty.

How do we use custom equals method for collection algorithm.

Comment: Use filter and a comparator

Comment: What else do you use `equals` for that means you can't just override it normally? Why do you need `equals1`?

Comment: Not on List but for example TreeSet takes a Comparator as a constructor parameter so you can have different types of equals through the comparator interface.

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos, Markspace : We can use the comparator for Sorting. So the comparator really resolve this problem.

Comment: @AndyTurner : I require two different methods, In case if I want to equal the Student object byname in eqauls method and byid in equals1 method. I don't want to add both condition in single method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `equals()` is special

remember that the `equals()` is special because the whole *collections* API relies on it.

Furthermore *collections* API (at least anything with "Hash" in its name like `HashSet` or `HashTable`) relies on the *relationship between `equals()` and `hashcode()`*: The deal is when ever `equals()` returns `true` both objects return the same value from `hashcode()`. On top of that the value retuned by `hashcode()` must not change during an objects lifetime.

Your implementation has the potential to break this rules forcing the *collections* API zu fail because your `equals1()` method uses the *mutable* field `name`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create equals wrapper that wrap you entity and your equals
its will be something like :

```
public class EqulasWrapper<T extends CustomHashCode> {

    T entity;
    BiFunction<T, T, Boolean> customEquals;


    public EqulasWrapper(T entityClass, BiFunction<T, T, Boolean> func){
        this.entity = entityClass;
        this.customEquals = func;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        EqulasWrapper<T> that = (EqulasWrapper<T>) o;
        return this.customEquals.apply(this.entity, that.entity);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return entity.getCustomHashCode();
    }


    public static class Person implements CustomHashCode {
        private int age;
        private String name;

        public Person(int age, String name) {
            this.age = age;
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCustomHashCode() {
            return age;
        }
    }

    public T getEntity() {
        return entity;
    }

    public BiFunction<T, T, Boolean> getCustomEquals() {
        return customEquals;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person = new Person(10, "Dan");
        BiFunction<Person, Person, Boolean> myCustomEqualsFunc =
                (p1, p2) -> p1.age == p2.age;

        EqulasWrapper<Person> personEqulasWrapper = new EqulasWrapper<>(person, myCustomEqualsFunc);

        Set<EqulasWrapper> mySet = new HashSet<>();

        mySet.add(personEqulasWrapper);

    }
```

The CustomHashCode interface look like:

```
public interface CustomHashCode {

    int getCustomHashCode();

}
```

short explanation

your set will use your custom Hash code that your entity implement and the custom equals your give him.

so you can create different collection with type  EqulasWrapper class
and design your hash code and your equals function has you wish, the collection instead of using original hash code and equals  will use with your wrapper

Hope I helped a bit
if you have any questions I would love to hear.